# Question of Excel formula if nested error

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested-if

I would like to make a formula on excel file which require to meet the following requirements:

1. If N column is empty, then nothing to do
2. If N column are not C and O, then show message of "invalid value"
   **(Remark: A,B,D,E.....M,N,P,Q....Z)**
3. If N column is C and T column is empty, then show message of "please write something here"

After run, it prompt up the error message of "**You've entered too many arguments for this function**". May I know what's wrong with me?

Thanks.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(N815),"", IF(OR(N815="C",N815="O"),"","Invalid Value!", IF(AND(N815="C",ISBLANK(T815)),"Please write something here!")))
```

Comment: You have done mistake in second IF false part. In place of `INVALID VALUE!` 3rd IF will be placed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry! I don't understand how to correct in second part of IF. Can you please help me? Much appreciated if you can help me.

Comment: You may try `=IF(ISBLANK(N815),"", IF(OR(N815="C",N815="O"),"Invalid Value!", IF(AND(N815="C",ISBLANK(T815)),"Please write something here!")))`

Comment: `If N column are not C and O, then show message of "invalid value"`  then this is not right :) `IF(OR(N815="C",N815="O"),"Invalid Value!"`

Comment: If you test each of your 3 if() statements individually, that would have shown your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know that you can indent your formula in the formula bar? :)

```
=IF(
    Something is True, 
    then do something, 
    otherwise do something else
   )
```

It is much easier to write when you want multiple `IFS`

```
=IF(
   ISBLANK(N815),
   "",
   IF(
     OR(N815="C",N815="O"),
     IF(
       AND(N815="C", ISBLANK(T815)),
       "Please write something here!",
       ""
       ),
     "invalid value"
     )
    )
```

[image]